# Angular - query json resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-resource, ngresource

I am trying to query a json file as ngResource to my controller, trying to follow following tutorial - https://devdactic.com/improving-rest-with-ngresource/

Only difference is i am trying to query a JSON file .

Service -

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
  .module('services')
     .factory('HeaderService', headerService);

headerService.$inject = ['$resource'];

function headerService($resource) {
    return $resource('/titles/dynamicTitles.json/:id', { id: "@id" });
}
})();
```

Controller is -

```
 function flowController(HeaderService) {
     console.log(HeaderService.get({ id: "/welcome" }));
}
```

dynamicTitles.json -

```
  [
  {
    "id": "/welcome",
    "title": "Welcome"
  },
  {
    "id": "/login",
    "title": "Login"
  }
 ]
```

console.log(HeaderService.query()); works fine but HeaderService.get({ id: "/welcome" })
is prompting error -> 404 not found.

Does angular takes care of the get(id) method or do i need to write the method?

Comment: server doesn't know what that path is. No point using `$resource` for a static file. Simple `$http` is all you need

Comment: Can i query json with http?

Comment: Yes...that's what it expects as default